# MVC scaffolding is great, until I need to extend my database schema

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, scaffolding

I'm using a code first approach to a simple web application: currently just a single table of book reviews.

I modified the model to include an extra column ("Rating"), and I also have an initialiser which correctly rebuilds the database every time I change the schema.

The problem is that none of the CRUD Views are updated to reflect the new "Rating" column. Do I have to modify each View by hand, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to manually add them. Scaffolding is intended for simple set up of views / controllers only.